# convert list of strings to panda dataframe with types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of a list of numbers where two rows are strings, e.g.

> A = [[1,'5.4','2'],[2,'6','3']]

How do I convert this to a pandas dataframe, such that the 1st and 3nd columns are integers and the 2nd column is a float

by

> pd.DataFrame(A,dtype=float)

it converts all to floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
pd.DataFrame(A).astype({0: int, 1: float, 2: int})
```

If you don't want to convert everything to a string and then change the type you could do something like this (everything is loaded as a float and then later you change the dtype of a few columns to int):

```
pd.DataFrame(A, dtype=float).convert_dtypes()
```

or

```
pd.DataFrame(A, dtype=float).astype({0: int, 2: int})
```

Comment: Great! This is what I want :)

Comment: @JakeB. Then please mark my answer as accepted and/or upvote it :)

Comment: I usually look at min max for each columns `df[0].describe()` and assign appropriate datatype. This can save up lots of memory space. `astype({0:"int8", 2:"float16"})`. information about ranges of each dtype can be found by `np.iinfo('int8')`, `np.finfo('float16')`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `applymap` with `pd.eval`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(A).applymap(pd.eval)
>>> df
   0    1  2
0  1  5.4  2
1  2  6.0  3
>>> df.dtypes
0      int64
1    float64
2      int64
dtype: object
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use `pd.to_numeric`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(A).apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

```
>>> df
   0    1  2
0  1  5.4  2
1  2  6.0  3

>>> df.dtypes
0      int64
1    float64
2      int64
dtype: object
```

If you have non numeric columns, use:

```
pd.DataFrame(A).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

Comment: If I have a very large dataframe (millions of elements), could it be avoided that I first convert to string and then to numeric? Because then I kinda use a lot of memory in the middle step.

Comment: Where the data come from? From a file?

Comment: From the web (returned from the server from a function in an API).
Thanks for your solution, it works in any case. It is probably fast enough, so why complicate?